# Browser showing strange Chinese like paragraphs

Tags: google-chrome, http

When I go to some websites using Google chrome, instead of showing the content my browser shows wired Chinese like paragraphs on the page, like this.

What should I do with this problem, should I be worried about this?  Please inform me what to do?

```
格浴㹬਍格慥㹤਍ഉऊ洼瑥⁡慮敭∽敤捳楲瑰潩≮挠湯整瑮∽敓⁴景眠汥⁬瑳畲瑣牵摥瘠摩潥琠瑵牯慩獬‬敨灬⁳潹⁵潴猠慴瑲挠摯楥湧瑩牥映潲⁭桴⁥慢楳獣挠牯敲瑣祬•㸯਍㰉楬歮爠汥∽瑳汹獥敨瑥•祴数∽整瑸振獳•牨晥∽振獳洯楡⹮獣≳ാऊ猼牣灩⁴祴数∽整瑸樯癡獡牣灩≴猠捲✽樯⽳煪敵祲洮湩樮❳㰾猯牣灩㹴਍㰉捳楲瑰琠灹㵥琢硥⽴慪慶捳楲瑰•牳㵣⼧獪栯扩牡洮湩樮❳㰾猯牣灩㹴਍㰉楬歮爠汥∽瑳汹獥敨瑥•祴数∽整瑸振獳•牨晥∽振獳瘯摩潥挮獳㸢਍㰉楬歮爠汥∽瑳汹獥敨瑥•祴数∽整瑸振獳•牨晥∽振獳洯湯歯楡挮獳㸢਍㰉楬歮栠敲㵦⼢敢楧湮牥⽳獲⹳浸≬爠汥∽污整湲瑡≥琠灹㵥愢灰楬慣楴湯爯獳砫汭•楴汴㵥䌢摯楥湧瑩牥嘠摩潥吠瑵牯慩⁬潦⁲敂楧湮牥≳⼠ാऊ਍उ琼瑩敬䌾摯楥湧瑩牥嘠摩潥吠瑵牯慩⁬潦⁲敂楧湮牥㱳琯瑩敬ാऊ਍਍㰉捳楲瑰琠灹㵥琢硥⽴慪慶捳楲瑰•牳㵣⼧獪栯杩汨杩瑨瀮捡⹫獪㸧⼼捳楲瑰ാऊ猼牣灩⁴祴数∽整瑸樯癡獡牣灩≴栾橬⹳湩瑩楈桧楬桧楴杮湏潌摡⤨㰻猯牣灩㹴਍਍㰉瑳汹⁥祴数∽整瑸振獳㸢਍਍उ琣灯挭愲笠਍उ瀉獯瑩潩㩮愠獢汯瑵㭥਍उ爉杩瑨›瀰㭸਍उ琉灯›〸硰഻ऊ紉਍਍㰉猯祴敬ാ㰊栯慥㹤਍戼摯㹹਍਍㰉楤⁶摩✽慬潹瑵㸧਍਍उ搼癩椠㵤栧慥楤杮㸧਍उ㰉楤⁶摩✽潬潧㸧愼栠敲㵦⼧㸧畔潴楲污䌠摯楥湧瑩牥猼灵猠祴敬✽潦瑮猭穩㩥〲硰✻‾爦来㰻猯灵㰾愯㨾㰠⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲‧摩✽潬潧摟捯❳䈾来湩敮獲⼼㹡⼼楤㹶਍उ㰉楤⁶摩✽楬歮❳ാऊउउ愼栠敲㵦⼧敢楧湮牥❳㸠敂楧湮牥⁳畇摩㱥愯‾⁼਍उउ㰉⁡牨晥✽愯瑲捩敬❳㸠牁楴汣獥⼼㹡਍उ㰉搯癩ാऊउ搼癩猠祴敬✽汣慥㩲戠瑯❨㰾搯癩ാऊ㰉ⴡ‭ ⴭാऊ㰉搯癩ാഊऊ㰉楤⁶摩✽潣瑮湥❴ാऊ਍उ㰉楤⁶摩✽慰敧楌瑳㸧਍उउ格㸲潔楰獣⼼㉨ാऊउ㰉汵ാऊउउ਍਍उउउഉऊउउउ氼㹩愼†汣獡㵳猧汥捥整❤牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲眯汥潣敭栮浴❬圾汥潣敭⼼㹡⼼楬ാऊउउउ਍਍उउഉഊऊउउउ਍उउउ㰉楬㰾⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲椯獮慴汬瑡潩⹮瑨汭㸧湉瑳污慬楴湯⼼㹡⼼楬ാऊउउउ਍਍उउഉഊऊउउउ਍उउउ㰉楬㰾⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲振摯楥湧瑩牥洭捶栮浴❬䌾摯楥湧瑩牥䴠䍖⼼㹡⼼楬ാऊउउउ਍਍उउഉഊऊउउउ਍उउउ㰉楬㰾⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲振摯楥湧瑩牥爭畯楴杮戭獡捩⹳瑨汭㸧潃敤杩楮整⁲潒瑵湩⁧慂楳獣⼼㹡⼼楬ാऊउउउ਍਍उउഉഊऊउउउ਍उउउ㰉楬㰾⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲振敲瑡湩ⵧ潣瑮潲汬牥栮浴❬䌾敲瑡湩⁧潃瑮潲汬牥⼼㹡⼼楬ാऊउउउ਍਍उउഉഊऊउउउ਍उउउ㰉楬㰾⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲振敲瑡湩ⵧ楶睥栮浴❬䌾敲瑡湩⁧楖睥⼼㹡⼼楬ാऊउउउ਍਍उउഉഊऊउउउ਍उउउ㰉楬㰾⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲振敲瑡湩ⵧ潭敤⹬瑨汭㸧牃慥楴杮䴠摯汥⼼㹡⼼楬ാऊउउउ਍਍उउഉഊऊउउउ਍उउउ㰉楬㰾⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲眯慨⵴敮瑸挭畯獲⹥瑨汭㸧桗瑡丠硥㱴愯㰾氯㹩਍उउउഉഊऊउउ਍਍उउउഉഊऊउउ਍਍उउउഉഊऊउउ਍਍उउउഉഊऊउउ਍਍उउ⼼汵ാഊऊउℼⴭठⴠ㸭਍उ㰉搯癩ാഊऊउ搼癩椠㵤瀧条❥ാഊऊउഉऊउउ਍उउഉऊउउ਍उउ਍उउ਍उउ格‱摩✽慰敧琭瑩敬㸧敗捬浯㱥栯㸱਍਍उउ਍਍उउ搼癩椠㵤挧湯整瑮㸧਍उउ㰉㹰椼杭猠捲✽椯慭敧⽳敢楧湮牥⽳潣敤杩楮整⵲畴潴楲污瀮杮‧污㵴䌧摯楥杮瑩牥吠瑵牯慩❬⼠㰾瀯ਾ㰊㹰桔獩椠⁳⁡敳⁴景眠汥⁬瑳畲瑣牵摥瘠摩潥琠瑵牯慩獬‬敨灬⁳潹⁵潴猠慴瑲挠摯楥湧瑩牥映潲⁭桴⁥慢楳獣挠牯敲瑣祬‮效敲礠畯⌦㈸㜱氻⁬敢氠慥湲湩㱧瀯ਾ㰊汵ਾ氼㹩潈⁷潴䤠獮慴汬䌠摯楥湧瑩牥⼼楬ਾ㰊楬䈾獡捩挠湯散瑰⁳敢楨摮䌠摯楥湧瑩牥⼼楬ਾ㰊楬䠾睯琠⁯敧⁴瑳牡整⁤楷桴挠摯湩㱧氯㹩㰊甯㹬㰊⁡牨晥✽戯来湩敮獲椯獮慴汬瑡潩⹮瑨汭㸧格㸲瑓牡⁴潎㱷栯㸲⼼㹡਍उउ⼼楤㹶਍਍उउ਍उ㰉搯癩ാऊउ搼癩猠祴敬✽汣慥㩲潢桴㸧⼼楤㹶਍਍उ⼼楤㹶਍਍उ搼癩椠㵤昧潯整❲ാऊउ敌牡⁮瑉䌠牯敲瑣ⴠ㈠㄰㰲牢ാऊउ潃敤杉楮整♲敲㭧椠⁳⁡敲楧瑳牥摥琠慲敤慭歲漠⁦愼栠敲㵦栧瑴㩰⼯汥楬汳扡挮浯✯䔾汬獩慌㱢愯ⰾ䤠据㰮牢‾桔獩眠扥猠瑩⁥獩愠⁮湩敤数摮湥⁴異汢捩瑡潩⁮湡⁤慨⁳潮⁴敢湥愠瑵潨楲敺Ɽ猠潰獮牯摥‬牯漠桴牥楷敳愠灰潲敶⁤祢䔠汬獩慌Ɫ䤠据മऊ㰉搯癩ാഊऊ⼼楤㹶਍਍㰉ⴡ‭呓剁⁔䅇䌠䑏⁅ⴭാऊ猼牣灩⁴祴数∽整瑸樯癡獡牣灩≴ാഊऊ†慶⁲束煡㴠张慧ⁱ籼嬠㭝਍ 张慧⹱異桳嬨弧敳䅴捣畯瑮Ⱗ✠䅕㌭〳㔸ㄵⴷ✱⥝഻ऊ†束煡瀮獵⡨❛獟瑥潄慭湩慎敭Ⱗ✠潮敮崧㬩਍† 张慧⹱異桳嬨弧敳䅴汬睯楌歮牥Ⱗ琠畲嵥㬩਍ 张慧⹱異桳嬨弧牴捡偫条癥敩❷⥝഻ഊऊ†昨湵瑣潩⡮ ൻऊ††慶⁲慧㴠搠捯浵湥⹴牣慥整汅浥湥⡴猧牣灩❴㬩朠⹡祴数㴠✠整瑸樯癡獡牣灩❴※慧愮祳据㴠琠畲㭥਍ †朠⹡牳⁣‽✨瑨灴㩳‧㴽搠捯浵湥⹴潬慣楴湯瀮潲潴潣⁬‿栧瑴獰⼺猯汳‧›栧瑴㩰⼯睷❷ ‫⸧潧杯敬愭慮祬楴獣挮浯术⹡獪㬧਍ †瘠牡猠㴠搠捯浵湥⹴敧䕴敬敭瑮䉳呹条慎敭✨捳楲瑰⤧せ㭝猠瀮牡湥乴摯⹥湩敳瑲敂潦敲木ⱡ猠㬩਍ 素⠩㬩਍਍㰉猯牣灩㹴਍㰉ⴡ‭久⁄䅇䌠䑏⁅ⴭാഊऊℼⴭ匠䅔呒䠠䉉剁丠呏䙉䍉呁佉⁎ⴭാऊ਍ഉऊℼⴭ䔠䑎䠠䉉剁丠呏䙉䍉呁佉⁎ⴭാഊ㰊戯摯㹹਍⼼瑨汭
```

Comment: Unless you are watching a very strange website, it is not the chinese translation of the context. Does it occur on many pages that look fine in other browsers or only specific ones? In the first case: have you tried reinstalling chrome?

Comment: hi, i haven't re-installed chrome? in some web pages all the content except some content is like this.  some content on the right of the page, or bottom of the page. i think some advertisements and stuff are shown like that.

Comment: Could you share a link to one of those sites so that others can check whether it is a chrome problem or problem of that website?

Comment: http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/ -> this full web site is shown in chinese, the above content is taken from the site.                                           http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/Back_Up_or_Copy_Outlook_Data.htm  -> this websites text under the right side Related Video is shown in chinese, but none of this problem occurs when i load these web sites in firefox.

Comment: Any chance you have told Chrome the page is encoded as UTF-16?

Comment: encoding is set to UTF-8, not as UTF-16 :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the very same characters when I explicitly set the character encoding to `UTF-16LE`, and the encoding setting persists when I reload the page.

Any chance you (or someone relative) have done the same by accident?

To fix, go to the `menu` > `Tools` > `Character Encoding` > `Auto-detect`.

Comment: encoding is set to UTF-8, not as UTF-16 :| , but i have a question, is there any way that add on i have used in chrome causing this? i have removed add block add on for chrome, now the pages are loading fine???

Comment: @ranganaMIT If the encoding is set to UTF-8, the page should display corectly. I don't know of any plugin that could force UTF-16, but I'm starting to think if there might be some confused proxy along the way, altering the headers or inserting a UTF-16LE byte order mark.

Comment: @ranganaMIT I'm wondering if a _very_ confused proxy might receive an UTF-8 page, think it's UTF-16 somehow (http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/ doesn't send a `content-encoding` header), and decice to re-encode to UTF-8? Then removing an extension most likely wouln't affect this - that is, unless the extension selects a proxy.