# Google chrome shows Chinese/strange encoding characters on pages

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox

I am using **chrome 20.0.1132.47**

#### I have gone through this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/536011/browser-showing-strange-chinese-like-paragraphs)  but that doesn't helped me.

Still Google chrome, instead of showing the s wired Chinese like paragraphs on the page, like this even I Set `menu > Tools > Character Encoding > Auto-detect`

[image: this].

### All working fine on Firefox

What should I do to solve this problem?

See what i Am searching and it is taking me to that link

[image]

Comment: That looks like you're looking at the Japanese language version, so which character(s) are not as you expect?

Comment: I see Japanese text, nothing creepy (although my Japanese is a little rusty, so I can't tell if it actually makes sense)

Comment: Also, Chrome **20**? Time to upgrade, no?

Comment: You're on the Japanese version of the page. Check the URL and remove the `/intl/ja` part. If this doesn't work, your system locale might be wrong, causing the browser to serve the wrong version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [image: red freehand circle 1]

**You're browsing the Japanese version of the website.** There is nothing wrong with the encoding. The text is *actually* in Japanese, not English.

Change the language at the bottom of the page:

[image: red freehand circle 2]

Comment: That worked like charm.